# Maximizing and minimizing $\sum (\lambda_{i+1}-\lambda_i)\lambda_{i+1}$

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, quadratic-programming

Suppose we have to choose a finite or an infinite sequence $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_T\}$ to maximize (or mimizize)
$$\sum_{i=1}^{T-1}(\lambda_{i+1}-\lambda_{i})\lambda_{i+1}.$$
When there are restrictions that it should be $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_{T}=0$, how can I proceed and find a solution? $\lambda_i$ should lie in between $0$ and $1$, i.e., $\lambda_i\in[0,1],\forall i$.

If the sequence is infinite ($T=\infty$), we can ignore the restriction $\lambda_T=0$.

In this case, what should be the maximum and minimum (or supremum and infimum) of  $\sum_{i=1}^{T-1}(\lambda_{i+1}-\lambda_{i})\lambda_{i+1}$?

Comment: $\lambda_{T+1}$ is undefined. Do you mean, that the sum should go from $1$ to $T-1$?

Comment: Hint: the gradient of the objective is $\mathbf{G}\mathbf{\lambda}$ where $\mathbf{G}$ is a tridiagonal matrix with $2$ in main diagonal and $-1$ in the subdiagonal

Comment: @thinkingeye Oh that's correct. I've changed T to T-1. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's not a proof, but numerical experimentation suggest me that you get the minimum with $\lambda_i = \frac{T-i}{T-1}$.

Comment: @thinkingeye Thanks for the guess from a numerical simulation! That indeed minimizes the objective. Those $\lambda_i$'s satisfy the first-order conditions (as well as the second order conditions)! The infimum of the objective function as $T$ approaches infinity is -1/2. I will have to work out the maximum now :)

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Thanks for the hint! I could come up with a minimizer using the gradient. But have no idea how to get the maximum.. The second order condition is not satisfied..

Comment: Do you need only one solution for each T?
It seems that for odd T, there are multiple solutions reaching the same maximum and for even T there is only one solution.

Comment: One pattern for $\lambda$ which works for all $T$ seems numerically be:
$\lambda_{even} = 0$ and $\lambda_{odd} = 1$ (but always $\lambda_T = 0$).
The maximum will then be: $\lfloor \frac{T}{2} \rfloor - 1$

Comment: @thinkingeye Right, by letting even lambdas 0 and odd lambdas 1, the sum keeps increasing as T increases! Thanks for the answer :) It is a great help to me!